# Total sum is less than sum of sums by tags in InfluxDB measurement?

Tags: influxdb

Or I am doing something wrong. I have a service that counts requests it receives. Requests have platform, version of client application that does them, and other tags. When service is restarted (which happens rarely on updates, metrics are reset).

So, I want to count percentage of queries from each platform in recent time range, and do:

```
SELECT SUM("received")  as "received"
FROM (
  SELECT NON_NEGATIVE_DIFFERENCE(MAX("received")) as "received"
  FROM  "http_metrics"
  WHERE time >= now() - 4h GROUP BY time(1s)
) GROUP BY "platform";
```

Which returns:

```
...
tags: platform=ios
time                 received
----                 --------
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 581

tags: platform=unknown
time                 received
----                 --------
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 12310

tags: platform=web
time                 received
----                 --------
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 6196
```

And do the same without grouping:

```
SELECT SUM("received")  as "received"
FROM (
  SELECT NON_NEGATIVE_DIFFERENCE(MAX("received")) as "received"
  FROM  "http_metrics"
  WHERE time >= now() - 4h GROUP BY time(1s)
);
```

Which returns:

```
time                 received
----                 --------
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 8274
```

Which is obviously incorrect, because "unknown" platform could not receive more requests than all of them. But I even don't know which is incorrect, total or by-platform or both?

How to count total and by-platform sum of requests properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that as my measurement had other tags, like server and app version, and separate counter for each of that, then they all become interleaved, which could be seen on a graph, which should be smooth and cumulative, but is very spiky:
[image: Received event measurement]

But when we add `GROUP BY *`

```
SELECT "received" FROM  "http_metrics"  WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY *;
```

It splits into lot's of separate smooth series:

[image: Counters increase slowly, so look horizontal]

Now, that is differentiable, and from that we could create subquery to aggregate from.

Total:

```
SELECT SUM("received") as "received" FROM (
    SELECT NON_NEGATIVE_DIFFERENCE(MAX("received")) as "received"
    FROM "http_metrics"
    WHERE time >= now() - 6h
    GROUP BY time(1s), *
) WHERE  time >= now() - 6h;

time                           received
----                           --------
2018-07-17T01:07:46.184292033Z 1367
```

Grouped:

```
SELECT SUM("received") as "received" FROM (
    SELECT NON_NEGATIVE_DIFFERENCE(MAX("received")) as "received"
    FROM "http_metrics"
    WHERE time >= now() - 6h
    GROUP BY time(1s), *
) WHERE  time >= now() - 6h
GROUP BY "platform";

... I'm not going to bore you with response, but sum matches total sum.
```

So, I guess moral the story should be: every time you want to differentiate counters which have some tags, you need to `GROUP BY *`